# Update Angular ngModel of a Select changed by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a 3rd party jQuery application that I have minimal control over, and I cannot and do not want to use anything else, so please don't tell me that I shouldn't do that... so this application make a `<select>` change to an empty value (that I have control) and I want my AngularJS ngModel to be made aware that jQuery changed that select to another value.
I can't seem to make it to work except using `eval()` and I seriously don't want to use that so I tried all kind of different solution but nothing is working (apart from `eval()` as I said). My solution would actually work if my ngModel would be a simple name (name), but it's in fact a complex name (object.name) and so this is were I'm stuck.

```
var optionObj = $('#selectId').val('');
angular.element(optionObj).triggerHandler('change');    // this fail
angular.element(optionObj).triggerHandler('onchange');  // this doesn't do anything

var scope = angular.element(optionObj).scope();
scope.$evalAsync(function(optionObj) {
    var ngModelAttr = optionObj.attr("ng-model"); // get the ng-model attribute     
    scope[ngModelAttr] = ''; // this does not work with complex object
    scope.user.language = ''; // this work, but cannot use it since ngModel naming is dynamic and unknown from within the code      

    console.debug(scope.user.language); // not empty 1st attempt, but empty on 2nd solution but is non-dynamic

    // using eval() works but it's dangerous
    eval("scope."+ngModelAttr+"=''");
}(optionObj));
```

So from the code that is there, and knowing our Angular looks like the following `<select ng-model="user.language">...</select>`, how can I advise Angular that jQuery made a change? Again don't forget the fact that I might know it's `user.language` here, but inside the jQuery application it doesn't know it, so everything has to be dynamically working. 

If I use `eval` then it works, but it's not only ugly but also dangerous...

Also worth to know that I'm using `AngularJS 1.3` and that is the reason why I use `$evalAsync()` instead of `$apply()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `scope.$eval()` to evaluate a string as code with the current scope as the context. It's safe to use because it will return `undefined` if the string happens not to reference an existing property, and the scope is the context for the evaluation, so trying to access properties not on the scope (like `window`) will also return `undefined`. You can use it like so:

```
var scope = angular.element(optionObj).scope();

scope.$evalAsync(function(optionObj) {

    var ngModelAttr = optionObj.attr("ng-model");

    scope.$eval(ngModelAttr + " = '' ");

}(optionObj));
```

Comment: sweet that does work, does it also sanitize the value somehow? Since you know `eval()` isn't safe to use...

Comment: Yep! The string is compiled as an Angular expression, which has several restrictions to prevent execution of unsafe code. You can learn more about expressions [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) and get the full details about `$eval()` [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$eval)

Comment: wow thanks a lot, this is indeed a great solution, I'll see if any other answers comes up, before accepting it, but so far your answer is the best ;)

Comment: looking at your code mixed with my code, I just saw that I actually doubt that the `scope.$evalAsync()` is useful anymore, I should go straight with just your code of `scope.$eval()`... thanks for this, it works great!

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm not sure I get everything you have going on here 100%, but maybe this will help..
I assume (and hope) that you have this control wrapped as a directive, right? So, would this just be as simple as passing your ngModel passed into the directive (with 2 way binding) and then setting the value of your variable with the jQuery element.

Please note this is pretty rough psuedo code just to give you an idea of what I mean:

In the view:

in the directive:

```
angular.module('myapp.directives').directive('MyDirective',myJqueyWrappedDirective);
function myJqueryWrappedDirecive(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'path/to/myTemplate.html', //you have your select element in a template
    scope: {
      myOuterNgModel: '=ngModelAttr'
     },
    link: function(scope,element){
      // #selectId is in your template
      $('#selectId').on('change', function(){ 
         scope.myOuterNgModel = $(this).val();
      }

    }
    }
```

The directive has 2 way binding to the the controller in the view so when your jquery element sets the value here, it changes the value in the outer scope controller.

Comment: thanks but unfortunately it's a 3rd party app, can't really use a Directive since it's not Angular but jQuery instead...